# Run MVC Application in Chrome from IIS 7.5

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, iis-7

I have hosted my MVC3 application in IIS 7.5. When I right click and browse it is opening in IE not in Chrome. How to configure to run website in Chrome by default.

Comment: i think IIS use the default browser. You can change the default browser (for the computer) in settings and that will be reflected here as well. This has nothing to do with `asp.net-mvc`

Comment: @mjwills From IIS, I choose my website name and when I right click I could see browse. When I click Browse, it is opening in IE.

Comment: @Shyju Is there any other option available to run in Chrome

Comment: You need to set your default system web browser. https://www.google.com.au/search?q=how+to+set+web+browser+windows+10

Comment: @Ask_SO just copy the url from IE and try in chrome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the Default Browser Setting in Windows like,

[image: Windows Default App Setting]

Answer (score 1):

Open it in IE then copy the URL, open Chrome and paste the URL.

Forgot to add, then hit return. :-)

Comment: Thanks. It works perfectly. But still is there any option available to directly open in Chrome.